# When fetching images from external storage images taken using camera is not shown in preview

Tags: android, bitmap

I am fetching images from external storage and uploading in to server. Before uploading I am showing a preview to the users using an imageview. Previews are shown for all the images, except when the files fetched are captured using the device camera. This is the code I am using:

```
uri = resultData.getData();
file = new File(Utils.getRealPathFromURI(activity,uri));
frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Bitmap bitmap  = Utils.getBitmapFromUri(activity,uri);
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStrea();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, bytes);
imageViewFilePreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: What kind of device are you using? Is there there any significant output in logcat?

Bitmaps captured taken with a highres camera can ve very exzessive in their memory consumption. Maybe you need to decode it down to a more memory friendly resolution bevor you attach it to a view

Comment: I'm using Redmi 6A

Answer (score 0):

You can call the cameraIntent() function in onclicklistner and while capture you can see preview and retry , after it will fetch in imageview

```
 private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
 }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
  }

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    user_image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```